# ¿Cómo usar un pipe de Angular en un input?

Tags: javascript, angular

Tengo un formulario con algunos campos donde necesito aplicarles un `pipe currency`. Mi formulario se ve algo así:

```
<form [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="enviarDatos()">
  <label for="consumo-mensual">Consumo mensual</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"
         formControlName="consumo-mensual" name="consumo-mensual" [(ngModel)]="numero">
</form>
```

Lo cual me arroja en consola una advertencia sobre la combinación de `ngModel` y `formControlName`. Donde indica que es una propiedad obsoleta para Angular 6 y 7.

```
  It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. 
  Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with 
  reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and will be removed 
  in Angular v7.

  For more information on this, see our API docs here:
  https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel
```

Además de estar obsoleto el usar `[(ngModel)]="numero | currency"` en mi pipe me da un muchos errores de consola.

Mi intención con estos campos es que cuando se escriba el ellos valores como:

```
1900
24700
19299433
```

El pipe `currency` los muestre como:

```
$1,900.00
$24,700.00
$19,299,433.00
```

¿Cómo podría lograr esto?

[EDIT] [Siguiendo esta respuesta][1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45794381/how-to-format-input-text-value-to-currency-on-angular-4-on-lost-focus) logré hacerlo funcionar aunque con algunos errores.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="numero"
       (keyup)="formatear($event)" [(value)]="numeroFormateado">
```

Y en mi archivo de typescript tengo lo siguiente:

```
formatear( element: any ) {
  this.numeroFormateado = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.numero);
  element.target.value = this.numeroFormateado;
}
```

Por ejemplo: Al presionar el `6` me aparece en el input `$6.00`. Pero el foco del input está a la derecha de `00`. Por lo que para escribir otro número tengo que borrar o recorrer hacia la derecha del `6`. Si escribiera un `5` para obtener un `65.00` obtengo el siguiente error de consola:

```
InicioComponent.html:4 ERROR Error: InvalidPipeArgument:
'$65.00 is not a number' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'
```

Después del error el pipe ya no funciona correctamente, ya que no formatea correctamente los valores.

Comment: Ya no se puede utilizar esas directivas simultáneamente, para que no te marque el error, te recomiendo utilizar el ngModel. Y el Pipe no funciona en los inputs, los pipes funcionan al mostrar la información, para eso deberías utilizar regex. Te dejo la documentacion de Angular. https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName

Comment: Utilizo regex para validar que los campos sean correctos, ¿Cómo podría utilizar una expresión regular para mostrar un número de esta manera?

Comment: @akko Los pipes son para formatear *salida* y los inputs son para editar *entrada*. Creo que no debes usar texto para cambiar el valor del input o mostrar el resultado del pipe en otro lugar.